# Are there a Dynamic programming solution that partition number and minimize the sum of absolute difference of each partition?

Tags: algorithms, dynamic-programming

Suppose given $n=2k$ numbers. We want partition numbers into two group $G_1,G_2$. Let $d_1$ be the largest value of absolute difference between each pair of numbers in $G_1$ and  also $d_2$ be the same as $d_1$ but in respect to numbers in $G_2$.
Our goal is each group contains exactly $k$ numbers and minimizing $d_1+d_2$.

Is there any Dynamic programming solution for the above problem? I think many days but I can't figure out the solution if exists.

Comment: I think that the problem admits an easy linear-time solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For simplicity I'll consider the case in which all numbers are distinct and $k \ge 2$. The argument below generalizes to the unrestricted case.

Let $G_1, G_2$ be the groups of an optimal solution and assume, w.l.o.g., that $\min G_1 \le \min G_2$.

Let $x=\max G_1$ and $y= \min G_2$.
We must have $x \le y$ since otherwise we would have $x > y$ and the sets $G_1^* = (G_1 \setminus\{x\}) \cup \{y\}, G_2^* = (G_2 \setminus\{y\}) \cup \{x\}$ would be a better solution.

Indeed: $(\max G_1^* - \min G_1^*) + (\max G_2^* - \min G_2^*) < (x - \min G_1) + (\max G_2 - y) = (\max G_1 - \min G_1) + (\max G_2 - \min G_2).$

Since $|G_1|=k$, it follows that $G_1$ must contain the smallest $k$ numbers, which can be found in linear time by finding the median of your set of numbers.

Comment: Thank you, I have two questions. 1. What is $\min G_1$ ? It return minimum number in $G_1$? 2. Can we use above argument for a sitution that input is points and we want minimze sum of diameter of   $G_1$ and $G_2$?

Comment: $\min G_1$ is the smallest number in $G_1$. I don't see an easy way to generalize the argument to $\mathbb{R}^2$.